# How to set session lifetime dynamically based on user role in laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I need to set session lifetime dynamically based on the logged-in user's role. I tried using middleware like below, but it does not work.
Also tried using `config(['session.lifetime' => 1]);` in the login method.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class UserLevelSessionSetter
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user && isCustomer($user)) {
            config(['session.lifetime' => 1]);
        } else {
            config(['session.lifetime' => 525600]); // 1 year
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't seem to work? What about it does not work?

Comment: config is global, is not related to a specific user.. you probably want to do this manually... e.g. in a middleware, if `session['start']` is not set, you set it to now, and then every time you check like `if(now - session['start'] > whatever you want) session_abort()`... obv, you would have to set the session time to 1 year and do this for normal user